# Java/ Android : Convert a Date like "2014-11-26T15:58:54.259+01:00" to current Locale

Tags: java, android, date

I got a date like "2014-11-26T15:58:54.259+01:00" from my Webservice
and i want to convert it to the locale configured on my device.
Here is what i have done so far :

```
String string = currentDatasetBundle.dataset.created_at;
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",Locale.GERMANY);
SimpleDateFormat outFormat = (SimpleDateFormat) android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getContext());
Date date;

String output = null;
try {
    date = inFormat.parse(string);
    output = outFormat.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
dateLabel.setText(output);
```

Everything works fine, but the Time wont show up inside my `output` String.
It looks like 11/26/2014 but I want to also show the Time like 11/26/2014 15:58:54 ?
What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [`android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getDateFormat%28android.content.Context%29) which only formats the date. Append [`android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getTimeFormat%28android.content.Context%29) to the output.

---

Full code:

```
String string = currentDatasetBundle.dataset.created_at;
SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",Locale.GERMANY);
Date date;

String output = null;
try {
    date = inFormat.parse(string);
    output = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getContext()).format(date)
        + " " + android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(getContext());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
dateLabel.setText(output);
```